# python c++ api PyRun_SimpleFile is not giving desired output

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to run a simple py file in dev c++.

```
    /// **main file**

    string script_name = "example.py"
    char* script_name2 = new char[script_name.length() + 1];
    
    strcpy(script_name2,  script_name.c_str());

    FILE* file_pointer;
    Py_Initialize();

    file_pointer = fopen(script_name2,"r");
    
    if (file_pointer == NULL)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        cout << "Cannot read file -> " << script_name2 << " ... exiting" << "\n";
        exit(0);
    }

    cout << file_pointer;
    
    PyRun_SimpleFile(file_pointer, script_name2);
```

example.py

```
print("My Name is TUTANKHAMEN")
```

The file pointer is not null and prints an adress.
example.py is in the same folder containing main.cpp

Below statement runs fine and prints output on console.

```
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import example\n");
    Py_Finalize();
```

Comment: What's the output, and what's with the *script\_name2* fiasco? what's your *OS*? https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags (the gray note).

Comment: If you're on Windows, you need to open the file in binary mode. (See the note on `PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html).)

Comment: please ignore script_name2. OS is windows. I am suspecting this has something to do with additional dependencies.

Comment: On a side note, you can pass `script_name.c_str()` directly to `fopen`, you don't need to copy it.

Comment: Opening in binary mode : " fopen(script_name2,"rb");  " doesn't work.

Comment: Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script runs fine Visual Studio 2019.

But in Dev C++ :

file_pointer = _Py_fopen(script_name2, "r");

This does the trick.